# openssl sha1 giving different results in the terminal vs in Python

Tags: python, openssl, sha1

I am trying to run an openssl command from a Python script, but am getting different sha1 values from the command executed in the script and the command executed directly in the terminal.

Here is my code:

```
command = "echo -n '" + hex(key)[2:] + "' | openssl sha1"
print(command)
os.system(command)
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
# This converts the bytes object to a string.
output = output.decode("utf-8")
print(output)
```

The `os.system(command)` is only there to check whether this method and `subprocess.check_output()` give the same result.

Here is the program output for an example input of `key=0xabc`:

```
echo -n 'abc' | openssl sha1
(stdin)= 9d4fe92b8bdc894f5838fad83108bf3841b257fa
(stdin)= 9d4fe92b8bdc894f5838fad83108bf3841b257fa
```

The first line is the command to be executed, the second is the result of the command using os.system() and the third is the result of the command using subprocess.check_output(). As you can see, both methods give the same result.

Now, if I copy and paste the command as it is displayed here and execute it in the terminal, this is the result:

```
(stdin)= a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d
```

Even though I copy and pasted the exact same command, the hash value output is different.

Even stranger, if I omit the `-n` option from `echo`, there is no inconsistency:

```
echo 'abc' | openssl sha1
(stdin)= 03cfd743661f07975fa2f1220c5194cbaff48451
(stdin)= 03cfd743661f07975fa2f1220c5194cbaff48451
```

And in the terminal:

```
(stdin)= 03cfd743661f07975fa2f1220c5194cbaff48451
```

Everything I have read online about similar issues stems from not using `-n`, rather than `-n` seemingly causing the issue. For the particular task I am doing, I have to use `-n` as I am computing the pre-image of a hash which was calculated using `echo -n "hash_value" | openssl sha1`.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*TL;DR*: use `/bin/echo`

*Explanation*:

The python system command is likely using a default shell of `/bin/sh` which is usually linked to a POSIX compliant shell, while your terminal session is using your user's login shell which is likely `bash`. POSIX shell standard does not support the `-n` option to the `echo` builtin function. This mean you are literally calculating the digest of "-n abc". You can reproduce this is bash like so:

```
echo "-n abc" | openssl sha1
9d4fe92b8bdc894f5838fad83108bf3841b257fa
```

The binary executable is still available but will need to be called by the full path since the shell builtin will override it. Instead of `echo`, use `/bin/echo`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was tearing my hair out over this :)

Comment: Another option is to use `printf`, which is portable.