# Inconsistent results with openssl when called from Python

Tags: python, openssl

Calling verify_sha256_hash(passcode, hash_expected) with

passcode, hash_expected = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', ''

The result is "94acf27cc065449e756a4f164ed5a7d6d53e51cc4112344dad890cece525c141"
instead of what we get from command line, thought they are calling the same openssl binaries.

That is,

$ echo "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" | openssl dgst -sha256
(stdin)= c03905fcdab297513a620ec81ed46ca44ddb62d41cbbd83eb4a5a3592be26a69

or
$ echo "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" | openssl sha256

(stdin)= c03905fcdab297513a620ec81ed46ca44ddb62d41cbbd83eb4a5a3592be26a69

Here are the Python codes for the calls:

```
def verify_sha256_hash(passcode, hash_expected):
    command = 'echo "' + passcode + '" | ' + openssl_path + 'openssl dgst -sha256'
    process_resultant = subprocess_cmd(command)

    if (process_resultant == hash_expected):
        print('Verification OK')
    else:
        print('Verification OK NOT')

    return

def subprocess_cmd(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    print("command: ", command)
    process_resultant = str(process.communicate()[0].strip())
    process_resultant = process_resultant.lstrip('b\'(stdin)= ').rstrip('\'')
    print("process_resultant: ", process_resultant)

    return process_resultant
```

How can this be corrected? Thanks.

Comment: I can not reproduce on macOS. Your example code works for me, I get the same result `c039...` for both methods (using python 3.7). Maybe your question is related to [openssl sha1 giving different results in the terminal vs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52782580/1380680)

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek, thank you. Mine is cygwin in windows. I do not have a mac. Could be software error. I tried echo -n "..." and it gave me f4a160684b0d89647ec7b93b6a0a75c7b552503fe634a7ff18f0a15b739cd2a4 instead. All these OS are wasting our time, there is no consistency, and I tried with Ubuntu. The answer is right. Looks like we are troubleshooting industrial packages. Instead of distributing bad packages, they should be deprecated, notified clearly and update. 

How we can help the industry with such needless confusion and costly wastage?

Thank you for helping the verification.

Comment: Does your shell have `printf`? You could try using that instead of `echo`, it tends to be more portable.